# Implement "ongoing" search after each text changing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, search, treeview

I have `Winforms` application and `TreeView`.
My `TreeView` if full of nodes (not so many, up to ~200) and i want to implement "ongoing" search after each text changing similar to Windows 7 & 8 search that after each text changing there is new search.
So i registered to my `TextBoxSearch_TextChanging event` and each text changing i am open new `Thread` and search for my string that the user typed and if my `node.Text` start with this latter/string this node become visible:

```
RadTreeView treeView;

private void radTextBoxSearch_TextChanging(object sender, TextChangingEventArgs e)
{
    string stringToSearch = radTextBoxSearch.Text.ToLower();
    ThreadStart ts = delegate
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
             foreach (RadTreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
             {
                 string nodeText = node.Text.ToLower();
                 if (!nodeText.StartsWith(stringToSearch))
                 {
                     node.Visible = false;
                 }
                 else
                     node.Visible = true;
             }                   
        });
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

So this is works fine except this little delay\UI stuck (for very little period of time) between types that i am encounter after every type so my question is there is way to improve this to become faster without this little delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a thread that calls `Invoke`, which causes the code to be executed on the UI thread. So there's no benefit to creating a separate thread.

The delay is probably due to the treeview updating after every node's visibility is set. I would suggest calling [SuspendLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `TreeView`  before the loop, and then [ResumeLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resumelayout(v=vs.110).aspx) when you're done, like this:

```
string stringToSearch = radTextBoxSearch.Text.ToLower();

treeView.SuspendLayout();
foreach (RadTreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
{
    string nodeText = node.Text.ToLower();
    node.Visible = nodeText.StartsWith(stringToSearch);
}
treeView.ResumeLayout();
```